# How do I switch between session handlers in run time?

Tags: php, session, redis, phpredis

I have **DB** session handler and I have a **FILE** session handler and a **REDIS** session handler

According to some logic in my bootstrap, I would like to choose which between the two session handlers I'll use for the current request.

How?

The code, before the `session_start` is

```
$c= $redis->pconnect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
if(!$c || !$redis->ping()){
  //do logic to switch to files/db session handler
}
```

Comment: By how you mean `ini_set("session.save_handler","files")` or something more?

Comment: Will that work? I must do it before SESSION START, right?

Comment: Of course it must be done before starting sessions. If you have DB session handler I assumed that you know something about it...

Comment: Your code is missing and your two session handlers are undefined. If you don't want to have your question to be an invitation to guessing but to get actual answers, please improve it.